# Delete rows in a select case structure

Tags: excel, vba

The code does nothing (no break appears with debug).

When the number of jeans is < 20 for US for instance, the code understand it's > 20. That's why it's not deleting any rows. The values in my "UI" sheet are numbers though.

```vb
Sub test()

Dim jeans As Double

Sheets("UI").Activate
last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To last_row 

    jeans = Cells(i, 8).Value

    If Cells(i, 3).Value = "US" Then
        Select Case jeans
        Case jeans < 20
            Rows(i).Delete
        Case Else
        End Select

    ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = "EU" Then
        Select Case jeans
        Case jeans < 10
            Rows(i).Delete
        Case Else
        End Select
    
    ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = "ASIA" Then
        Select Case jeans
        Case jeans < 10
            Rows(i).Delete
        Case Else
        End Select

    Else
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? When deleting rows always loop backwards.

Comment: I just did, thank you, but it's very odd because when the number of jeans is < 20 for US for instance, the code understand it's > 20. That's why it's not deleting any rows. The values in my "UI" sheet are numbers tho.

Comment: Oops just noticed syntax problem. Should be `Case is <20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Loop Backwards With Conditions

- You need to loop backward, from the bottom to the top to cover all cells.
- When a code is doing nothing, check if there is data in the column where you're calculating the last row, that is column `A` in this case.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LoopBackward()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UI")
        
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim Jeans As Double
        Dim r As Long
        
        For r = LastRow To 2 Step -1
            
            Jeans = .Cells(r, "H").Value
            
            Select Case .Cells(r, "C").Value
            Case "US"
                If Jeans < 20 Then .Rows(r).Delete
            Case "EU", "ASIA"
                If Jeans < 10 Then .Rows(r).Delete
            Case Else
                .Rows(r).Delete
            End Select
        
        Next r
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't knew loop backwardation before